# Pandas pd.to_datetime() removing duplicate values

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I've been trying to sort a date column, but I needed to convert the string date to date value format. However I'm losing duplicate dates, but I need the duplicates.

Here's my code:

```
import pandas as pd

df_in = pd.read_csv(input.csv)
df_in['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df_in['date'],format='%Y%m%d').dt.date
df_in.to_excel("output.xlsx")
```

Am I missing something in my method call?
below is a comparison of the input (left side) and output (right side) files:
[image]

Comment: So data are converted to misisng values `NaT`, if use `df_in['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df_in['date'],format='%Y%m%d')` only? Or problem is in to_excel and converting is correct?

Comment: @jezrael There's available data, but when exported to excel it's just non existent. If you see in the left side of the image there's data in the respective rows.